# how can i fix ckeditor problems

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I use from `ckeditor` in laravel .. but after saving the text ... laravel show the text with `html` tag in website. like this

`<p>Hello</p>`

```
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="simpleinput">پیشنمایش مطلب</label>


                <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <textarea name="description"></textarea>

                </div>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description',{
                        language:'fa',

                    } );

                </script>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where are you outputting the text in this view?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got CKEditor set up correctly and it is storing the rich text (with HTML) into your database.

If you are outputting the text with Laravel's blade, to remove the HTML (e.g. `<p>`), use the unescaped syntax: `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`

`<p> Hello </p>` will appear as `Hello` inside `{!! <p> Hello </p> !!}`

Comment: @foad el - were you able to test your code with this?  I am curious how it turned out, as this is very likely the solution.